# Can somebody please tell me what font this is?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, style-identification, font-design

Its very edited but I'm pretty sure each letter is easily identifiable. Help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Endorlight Logo]

Answer (score 1):

It's AmazObitaemOstrov, the letters are capitals except O and H which are lower case.

[image]

Comment: Did you know that [answering such badly-stated questions will only increase their number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory)?

Comment: @usr2564301 I have got warnings from high rank members. As long as I'm not definitively fired, I give answers to questions that I see at least a little interesting. and answerable with my limited knowledge. Font identification cases mostly aren't such, but this was.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a self-made font to me.
1. because it's their logo.
2. it really looks like they took a random bold font and cut some the edges.
For me, it looks like they used it based on [this font](https://www.dafont.com/de/moon-get.font).